# How to define two times globalsize for two different kernels with different work items?

Tags: kernel, opencl

How to create two different types of global size, my problem is i have two kernels, for both the global size is different, for example for 1st kernel i am working with 16 num of threads, for 2nd kernel i need 96 threads. how can i assign my globalsize according to this criteria. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the functions enqueuendrange and enqueuendrangekernel. Since you are using two different kernels, you need to call them separately anyway. You would pass different values in the size parameters of this function.

However, if you are trying to execute these kernels at the same time, not all devices support device fission. Check out the extension 'cl_ext_device_fission' and if your device supports it.